# SharePoint WSP deployment and list item data loss

Tags: sharepoint-server

Very peculiar thing happened today in our QA server.
In our QA we have custom lists and custom workflows installed and running.
Recently we made some changes to the workflow and deploy the wsp in QA server. After this, all list item's single line of text column field values were empty.
Please note, items remain as is, but only the field values were missing or blank.

What would be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Are the list items created by a feature in the WSP?  It is probably a question for the developer of the solution, but I would imagine certain things happen with those items on feature activation, deactivation, or both.